# Can AWS CodeBuild publish nuget packages to Nuget.org and Github?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuget, aws-codebuild

I am developing a nuget package. It has a public Github repo. Is it possible to use AWS CodeBuild to perform the following actions after dev branch is merged to master:

1. Build master in release
2. Get nupkg file from bin/release folder and publish it to nuget.org
3. Add that same file as a release to the github repo
4. start a custom *.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build master in release

Use Webhook with CodeBuild to build any branch:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html

> Get nupkg file from bin/release folder and publish it to nuget.org

CodeBuild can run any arbitrary command in buildspec:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-example

> Add that same file as a release to the github repo

I am not sure, you may need to use a third party binary to achieve this which is run in buildspec

> start a custom *.exe

Will you run this during build or deploy? If build, you can again run the command in buildspec, if deploy, you need to use a deploy service like CodeDeploy.

Comment: `start a custom *.exe` the exe is a separate application, not found in the repo which would be built.